# Receiving multiple TCP segments

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I have an assignment in which a TCP client sends data to the TCP server in the form of:

IP_address\0port\0message\n

Now, the server (IP address 10.0.2.15) receives the packet fine when I send some data through a terminal like this:

```
printf "127.0.0.1\0004444\000Some message\n" | nc -N 10.0.2.15 3333
```

However, the second part of the assignment is to read a packet that comes in multiple segments:

```
(printf "127.0.0.1"; sleep 0.3; printf "\0004444\000"; sleep 0.3; \
printf "It works"; sleep 0.5; printf "\n") | nc -N 10.0.2.15 3333
```

How should I implement the read function on the server so that, if possible, all the segments are stored into a buffer?

Comment: How would you implement it if it didn't come in multiple segments? Is there any difference? Note you don't know the length of the message beforehand.

Comment: @n.m. I'd use a simple read function like so: https://pastebin.com/RjVdVKmS

Comment: What is BUF_SIZE? **You don't know the length of the message beforehand**.

Comment: So I can't receive a message in multiple segments without knowing the length first? BUF_SIZE is the maximum allowed size of the message (512 bytes in this case).

Comment: (1) *So I can't receive a message in multiple segments without knowing the length first?* I didn't say anything like that. *512 bytes in this case* OK now can  you **pretend** you don't know the length of the message? Pretend it can be 1000, or 10000, or 100000000 characters. Can you read it now, somehow, without considering the multiple segments issue? Pretend it comes from a file. Can you read a line of an arbitrary length?

Comment: (2) `man read` says *On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end of file), and the file position is advanced by this number. It is not an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes requested; this may happen for example because fewer bytes are actually available right now (maybe because we were close to end-of-file, or because we are reading from a pipe, or from a terminal), or because read() was interrupted by a signal.* You need to take this into account when you call `read`.

Comment: The problem is, when it sends the first part of the message, the read() unblocks and continues execution of the program. How would I be able to check whether all the segments have been sent?

Comment: Perhaps check if `\n` is present in the message. How else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of bytes `recv()` returns can be as few as 1 byte up to as many bytes as requested. TCP is a byte stream, it has no concept of messages, that has to be handled in the application code instead.

The receiver must know how many bytes to expect, and then keep reading in a loop until it has read that many bytes, however many reads it takes.

However, in this situation, the receiver does not know the exact length of the message, because the sender is not sending the message length before sending the message itself, so the only option available is for the receiver to read from the socket byte-by-byte until it encounters the terminating `\n`.

For example:

```
int readLine(int socket, char **line)
{
    int r, len = 0, cap = 256;
    char b;

    *line = NULL;

    char *outline = (char*) malloc(cap);
    if (!outline) return -2;

    do
    {
        r = recv(socket, &b, 1, 0);
        if (r <= 0)
        {
            free(outline);
            return r;
        }

        if (b == '\n')
            break;

        if (len == cap)
        {
            cap += 256;
            char *newline = (char*) realloc(outline, cap);
            if (!newline)
            {
                free(outline);
                return -2;
            }
            outline = newline;
        }

        outline[len] = b;
        ++len;
    }
    while (true);

    if ((len > 0) && (line[len-1] == '\r'))
        --len;

    if (len == cap)
    {
        char *newline = (char*) realloc(outline, cap + 1);
        if (!newline)
        {
            free(outline);
            return -2;
        }
        outline = newline;
    }

    outline[len] = '\0';

    *line = outline;

    return 1;
}
```

```
char *line;
int r;

do
{
    r = readLine(cliSock, &line);
    if (r <= 0)
    {
        if (r == 0)
            printf("client disconnected\n");
        else if (r == -2)
            printf("memory error\n");
        else
            printf("read error\n");
        break;
    }

    // process line as needed...

    free(line);
}
while (true);
```

Alternatively, you can use an intermediate buffer to help you cache data between reads and get data out of the socket more efficiently:

```
char *buffer;
int buflen, bufcap;

int readLine(int socket, char **line)
{
    char *ptr;
    int r, idx = 0;

    *line = NULL;

    do
    {
        ptr = memchr(buffer + idx, '\n', buflen - idx);
        if (ptr)
        {
            int total = ((ptr + 1) - buffer);

            int len = (total - 1);
            if ((len > 0) && (buffer[len-1] == '\r'))
                --len;

            *line = (char*) malloc(len + 1);
            if (*line == NULL)
                return -2;

            memcpy(*line, buffer, len);
            (*line)[len] = '\0';

            if (total < buflen)
                memmove(buffer, buffer + total, buflen - total);
            buflen -= total;

            break;
        }

        if (buflen == bufcap)
        {
            int newcap = bufcap + 256;
            char *newbuffer = (char*) realloc(buffer, newcap);
            if (!newbuffer)
                return -2;
            buffer = newbuffer;
            bufcap = newcap;
        }

        r = recv(socket, buffer + buflen, bufcap - buflen, 0);
        if (r <= 0)
            return r;

        buflen += r;
    }
    while (true);

    return 1;
}
```

```
buflen = 0;
bufcap = 256;
buffer = (char*) malloc(bufcap);
if (buffer)
{
    char *line;
    int r;

    do
    {
        r = readLine(cliSock, &line);
        if (r <= 0)
        {
            if (r == 0)
                printf("client disconnected\n");
            else if (r == -2)
                printf("memory error\n");
            else
                printf("read error\n");
            break;
        }

        // process line as needed...

        free(line);
    }
    while (true);

    free(buffer);
}
```